# How to access specific properties in a multiple objects using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, properties

Here is my object:

```
$scope.info = [];
$scope.info = [{"name":"kanye","size":"","folder":"Folder"},{"name":"west","size":"","folder":"Folder"}]
$scope.infoObj = $scope.info.name;
console.log($scope.infoObj);
```

This return me Undefined. The response should be like this:

```
[{"name":kanye},{"name":west}]
```

But how to access the specific properties from a multiple object using angularJS or jquery/js?

Comment: Note that `[]` means ***Array***, which are generally accessed with things like `[0]`, so maybe you should try `$scope.info[0].name`

Comment: I tried it already but only the value from info[0].name showed. Example: {"name": kanye}.

Comment: The console should print  `kanye` as that's the name of the first object, the one in the `[0]` position in the array. To get the second one you'd do `$scope.info[1].name` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do a little bit of refactoring to make your code a little cleaner and more readable. Instead of setting your `info` value twice, set it once, and add the objects in each line after.

Like this:

```
$scope.info = [];
$scope.info.push({
  "name":"kanye",
  "size":"",
  "folder":"Folder"
});
$scope.info.push({
  "name":"west",
  "size":"",
  "folder":"Folder"
});
```

See how clean that is?  Now it should be fairly obvious that `info` is an *Array* of objects, so doing `$scope.info.name` won't work.  What I would recommend is creating a lookup function that can help grab a list based on the key you provide it.

Something like this:

```
function lookup(key) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.info.length; i++) {
    var object = {};
    object[key] = $scope.info[i][key];
    result.push(object);
  }
  return result;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
$scope.infoObj = lookup('name');
console.log($scope.infoObj);
```

Answer (score 4):

This should solve the problem:

```
$scope.infoObj = $scope.info.map(function(obj){ 
  var x = {}; 
  x['name'] = obj['name']; 
  return x;
})
```

for ES6, it can be simplified to:

```
$scope.infoObj = $scope.info.map(x => ({name:x['name']}))
```

Comment: or `$scope.info.map(obj=>({name: obj.name});`